# Disable button until another is pressed and disable it again if cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have an excel worksheet with 2 buttons.

Is it possible to have the first button disabled until the second button is clicked AND then have the first button disabled if the cell value in B2 changes at all (so it would be re-enabled by clicking on the second button again)?

**Context**

This excel file is connected to an SQL server database and the users I'm giving this to will use it to view and update entries from an SQL table. They would view details by typing in an ID in B2 then clicking the second button which would fill out a table below (showing details for that ID) and if they want to make any changes they'd edit the table below and click on the first button.

The trouble with this is that if for instance they simply type an ID in B2, go to the empty table below, put a value in just one of the columns and click on the first button, it would set all other columns for that ID to be blank, simply because they didn't choose to view the ID in the first place and tried to skip a step.

**What I've tried**

On the 2nd button I have the following:

```
UpdateDetails.Enabled = True
```

where UpdateDetails is the name of the first button.

On the worksheet itself I have

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2")) > 0 Then
    UpdateDetails.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

So far I can enable the first button by clicking on the second button but the issue is that if I make any changes to the worksheet outside of B1 the first button gets disabled again; I only want it disabled if the value of B1 changes.

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: I tried it using your code, and it seems to work just fine. If B2 is changed to anything but a blank cell, the first button is disabled. Clicking the second button enables button 1 regardless of the content of B2. Are you using ActiveX Buttons? or Form Buttons? In my example, I am using ActiveX buttons.

Comment: initially I was using form buttons. I'm using ActiveX now and it's at least enabling the first button by clicking the second button but the issue is that the first button is being disabled whenever I make any changes to the worksheet (it should only be disabled when a change is made to B2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Target parameter address to see which cell is being changed too.. like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2")) > 0 And Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False
  End If
End Sub
```

It may run faster coded like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' This way it only runs the CountA check in that one instance
  If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then 
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B2")) > 0 Then
      CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```